# Matplotlib: `pcolormesh.get_array()` returns flattened array - how to get 2D data back?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to get the data values along a line (like in [this hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878398/how-to-extract-an-arbitrary-line-of-values-from-a-numpy-array)).  That example uses `imshow()`, but I'm currently using `pcolormesh()` to plot.

I'm finding that the `get_array()` function, to grab plotted data from `pcolormesh()` is returning a 1-D, flattened array of my data, instead of the original (or truncated) 2-D data.

For example:

```
D = np.genfromtxt(DataFilePath, skip_header=4, delimiter=',', unpack=True)
print( D.shape )
: (500, 500)

...more code...

img = ax[0].pcolormesh( np.arange( len(D[0,:]) ), np.arange(len(D[:,0])), D)

>>> D
: array([[ 42.38,  41.93,  41.92, ...,  41.73,  41.74,  41.51],
       [ 41.88,  42.24,  42.21, ...,  41.88,  41.67,  41.64],
       [ 42.4 ,  41.47,  41.49, ...,  41.92,  42.07,  41.49],
       ..., 
       [ 44.24,  44.14,  44.17, ...,  40.2 ,  40.68,  40.67],
       [ 44.59,  44.24,  44.3 , ...,  40.91,  40.92,  40.95],
       [ 44.2 ,  44.27,  44.27, ...,  40.82,  40.91,  40.94]])
>>> img.get_array()
: array([ 42.38,  41.93,  41.92, ...,  40.85,  40.91,  40.92])
```

Since I'm trying to grab user-clicks on the plot and then re-plot using the clicked data values (like in [this hint](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html)), I would like to use a function/class which **won't have global access to the original data**, but does have access to the `img` object.

Any idea how I get the 2D data from `pcolormesh()` using only the `img`(QuadMesh) object?  It doesn't even seem to have the x/y length/shape values, for me to reconstruct the data from the 1-D `get_array()`.

Thanks!

Comment: It's like `pcolormesh` ran `np.ravel()` on the data and stroed it in `get_array()` - any way to `unravel`?

Comment: What kinds of user changes do you expect to see?

Comment: Just want to get the plotted data values along a line between the points the user clicked & then let go - this will occur inside the event-handler class that only gets access to the `img` (QuadMesh) object, but can't access the original Data array.

Comment: Then the `img` attributes the @unutbu mentions are the way go.

Comment: posted the whole function here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878398/how-to-extract-an-arbitrary-line-of-values-from-a-numpy-array/34848130#34848130

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shape of the array in stored in private attributes, [`_meshWidth` and `_meshHeight`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/collections.py#L1749). Nevertheless, since these attributes are not part of the public API, it would be better to save the shape of the original data than to rely on these if possible.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

D = np.random.uniform(0, 100, size=(5, 5))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
h, w = D.shape
img = ax.pcolormesh( np.arange(h+1), np.arange(w+1), D)

D2 = img.get_array().reshape(img._meshWidth, img._meshHeight)
assert  np.array_equal(D, D2)
```

Note also that if you wish to recover the original array `D`, then the coordinate arrays, `np.arange(h+1)`, `np.arange(w+1)` must have lengths one bigger than the shape of `D`. Otherwise, `img.get_array()` returns an array of shape `(499, 499)` when `D` has shape `(500, 500)`.

Comment: From `_pcolorargs` it looks like `pcolor` will lop off points from `C` if needed to match `x` and `y`.

Comment: ah, the `_meshWidth` & `_meshHeight` values are what I needed to reproduce something like the original array.  Unfortunately, coding these attributes makes my function now *only* work for `pcolormesh` - if there was a general API call (like `get_width()`/`get_height()`), my function would work for `pcolor`, `pcolormesh`, and maybe also `contourf` and others.  Maybe should submit a feature request...

Comment: I added some notes on what `pcolor` produces - it divides the mesh into many simple quadrilaterals, so it's `img` does not have any notion of mesh height or width.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does ravel the inputs:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py

```
    # convert to one dimensional arrays
    C = C.ravel()
    X = X.ravel()
    Y = Y.ravel()
```

If you know the desired 2d shape, you can unravel with a simple `reshape` call.

If the result should have the same shape as `D` use:

```
img.get_array().reshape(D.shape)
```

If the size of the raveled `C` can change, then this won't work.

---

If I make a `D` array that is `(10,20)`, and plot it

```
img = pyplot.pcolormesh(D)
```

`img._A` is (200,), the array that `img.get_array()` returns.

```
img._meshHeight, img._meshWidth
# 10, 20
```

So the array can be reshaped with:

```
img._A.reshape(img._meshHeight, img._meshWidth)
```

`img._coordinates` is a (11,21,2) array, the coordinates in the x and y direction, plus one point.  So you could get the `C` reshaping information from `_coordinates` as well.  I don't see any public API method for retrieving these attributes, but that doesn't stop 'serious' Python programmers.  In this test case, it generated the `coordinates` from the shape of `D`.

This `Quadmesh` was created with:

```
    coords = np.zeros(((Nx * Ny), 2), dtype=float)
    coords[:, 0] = X
    coords[:, 1] = Y

    collection = QuadMesh(
        Nx - 1, Ny - 1, coords, ...)
    ....
    collection.set_array(C)
```

A search for `get_array` in the `matplotlib` github repository does not get many hits.

---

I dug into the `pcolor` code a bit. It returns a `PolyCollections` img rather than a Quadmesh.  It contains the information for drawing a collection of quadrilaterals.

For example in my test case with a 10x20 input, `img._paths` is a list of 200 `Path` objects

```
In [486]: img1._paths[0]
Out[486]: 
Path(array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.]]), array([ 1,  2,  2,  2,  2, 79], dtype=uint8))
```

It has five coordinate pairs, the `xy` points needed to draw the boundary of the quad, which will have a color value corresponding to `C[0]` (in the raveled form).

So all the `X` `Y` grid information is now coded in these `Path` objects.  Instead of plotting a mesh it plots 200 colored squares (quads).  The `PolyCollections` code does not assume that the squares are in any order or even touching each other.  The big picture has been replaced with a bunch of independent small pictures.

You might be able reassemble those quads into a mesh, looking for matching vertices, etc.  But it would be a lot of work.

Comment: My function won't have access to the original data `D` unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, that is really interesting. Have you, in your research, come across a way that would work for the various types of surface/2D plotting? I haven't tried it yet, but I am wondering if the '_coordinates' method could work for not just 'Pcolormesh', but also 'Pcolor', or 'ContorF'.

Comment: The `pcolor` `img` doesn't have a `_coordinates` attribute.  The only place I could find the xy values was in `._paths`.  I looked in both the code and a sample `img` object (via `ipython`).