# Return row/column values from array underneath lines

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, line

What I'm trying to do is generate multiple lines on a binary image based on a length and angle. Then return all of the row/column values along with pixel values underneath those lines and place them into a python list.
To generate those lines I wrote a function that outputs start and end coordinates of each line. Using these coordinates I want to generate the lines and extract the values.

To extract values from a horizontal line from pixel (0,1) to (3,1) I can do:

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])
pixels = a[1, 0:3]
```

or vertical:

```
pixels = a[0:3, 1]
```

which returns an array of all the pixel values underneath that line:

```
array([3, 4, 5])
array([1, 4, 7])
```

How could I apply this method on lines with an angle? so with an x1,y1 and x2,y2? These return (syntax) errors:

```
a([0,0], [2,2])
a([0,0]:[2,2])
a[0,0:2,2]
```

I'm looking for something similiar as '[improfile](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/improfile.html)' in Matlab.
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878398/how-to-extract-an-arbitrary-line-of-values-from-a-numpy-array ?

Comment: Thank you for the link. I had not found that topic yet, very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scikits-image's `draw` module and the [draw.line](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.draw.html#skimage.draw.line) method:

```
>>> from skimage.draw import line
>>> y0 = 1; x0 = 1; y1 = 10; x1 = 10;
>>> rr, cc = line(y0, x0, y1, x1)
```

`rr` and `cc` will contain row and column indexes of the values from which the line passes. You can access those values as:

```
>>> values = img[rr, cc]
```

Assuming `img` is the name of your image.

Note that this implementation does not offer interpolation or subpixel accuracy for angles different from 45 degree intervals. It will create a discrete stepped line between points A and B that passes through whole pixels.