# How to extract an arbitrary line of values from a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

i want to extract an interpolated straight line between two arbitrary points from a equidistant 3D matrix, such as:

```
data_points_on_line=extract_line_from_3D_matrix(matrix,point1,point2,number_of_data_values_needed)
```

with the 3D matrix `matrix`, start and end point `point1`,`point2` and the resolution of returned data between `point1` and `point2` given by an integer with `number_of_data_values_needed`.

i know that it's pretty simple when extracting data from a 2d array with `scipy.ndimage` but does anybody know whether there's already a function in `scipy` or `numpy` which can do that in 3D?

many thanks in advance!

Comment: sounds like scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator could be of help. Can you show what exactly you would do in the 2d case and why it doesn't work for 3d? This way it should be easier to understand your problem

Comment: ok. i'll check that function. in 2d i would do it this way: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878398/how-to-extract-an-arbitrary-line-of-values-from-a-numpy-array) but a point somewhere within the matrix basically depends on data values in three spatial dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

it works for me using InterpolatingFunction, for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np

from Scientific.Functions.Interpolation import InterpolatingFunction

def linear_interp_3d(point1,point2,spacing):
    xi=np.linspace(point1[0],point2[0],spacing)
    yi=np.linspace(point1[1],point2[1],spacing)
    zi=np.linspace(point1[2],point2[2],spacing)

    return xi,yi,zi

n=4
x = np.arange(0, n, 1)
y = np.arange(0, n, 1)
z = np.arange(0, n, 1)

data = np.ones(shape = (n, n, n))
for dummy in range(n):
    data[dummy,:,:]=dummy**3
axes = (x,y,z)
f = InterpolatingFunction(axes, data)

point1=(0,0,0)
point2=(3,3,3)
linevals=linear_interp_3d(point1,point2,11)

line=[]
for dummy in range(len(linevals[0][:])):
    line.append(f(linevals[0][dummy],linevals[1][dummy],linevals[2][dummy]))
print line
```