# How to extract a One dimensional profile along a curve using Geographic/Co-ordinates instead of pixel Coords?

Tags: indexing, maps, slice, scikit-image, cartopy

[image]
How do I get the 1D profile from an Array given geographic coordinates instead of pixel coordinates.
I have radiance data in Geo-coordinates ([NASA GOLD Mission](https://gold.cs.ucf.edu/data/search/)).
The data for each hemisphere is stored in a separate file. I want to take a 1D profile of the spliced hemispheres along a curve (10 degNorth dip latitude) which is in Geo coords,

I tried to adapt the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878398/how-to-extract-an-arbitrary-line-of-values-from-a-numpy-array) using [map_coordinates](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj-rt7YgeL9AhWqrJUCHRpXAu4QFnoECA4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.scipy.org%2Fdoc%2Fscipy%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fscipy.ndimage.map_coordinates.html&usg=AOvVaw1F6c1Lvo2MwnydrEm8zf1I) but I realised it is in pixel coordinates that is why I believe the profile does not correspond to the map;
To get the 1D profile I plotted the output from mapcoords against the input curve (X) values so as to get the variation against longitude.
The other profile in yellow also does not correspond to the data in the map;
When I plot the data using imshow it does not look the same as on the map;
[image: imshow of data]

The data and Python Code is here [Data+Code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tDwitLHtNMhpdqyuYsPXQHGabnTW1hs3?usp=sharing);

[image: GOLD map and 1D profile along 10 deg North dip]

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset  
import glob, matplotlib,os;matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy.ma as ma

Mag = pd.read_csv(r"\mag_cords.csv")
X_dip10s,Y_dip10s = Mag.LON10S.to_numpy(),Mag.LAT10S.to_numpy()
g = Dataset('GOLD_L1C_CH*23*.nc','r'); 
wavelength = g.variables['WAVELENGTH'][:]
radiance = g.variables['RADIANCE'][:]
lat = g.variables['REFERENCE_POINT_LAT'][:] 
lon = g.variables['REFERENCE_POINT_LON'][:] 
g.close()
O5s_ids = np.argwhere((134.3 <= wavelength[50,25,:]) & (wavelength[50,25,:] <= 137.7))
O5s = np.array(np.nansum(radiance[:,:,O5s_ids],axis = 2))*.04 # integrate under the peak!
O5s = np.transpose(O5s[:,:,0])
x=lon[9:-8,9:-8];y=lat[9:-8,9:-8];z=O5s[9:-8,9:-8].T;z=abs(z)#To remove Nans
z2=np.ma.masked_array(z, (z > 30)) 

Zs=scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates(np.transpose(z),
np.vstack((X_dip10s,Y_dip10s)),
mode="nearest")
Xs=scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates(np.transpose(x),
np.vstack((X_dip10s,Y_dip10s)),mode="nearest") 
                                                                                                                         
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
axarr = fig.add_subplot(211,projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
grid_lines =axarr.gridlines(draw_labels=True'); axarr.coastlines()
cs1 = axarr.contourf(x,y, z2, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),cmap='jet',levels=50)
ax2.plot(X_dip10s,Zs, 'k-', Xs ,Zs, 'k-')


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/66C4P.png
```

Comment: I also want the map to line up with the 1D profile so the x axis are identical.

Comment: To clarify, the data is from a Geostationary satellite which measures radiance at various wavelengths. The data is geo-referenced to lat and lon cords on Earth. I want to extract the profile using IGRF dip latitude eg along the magnetic equator (which is different from the geographic equator) dip Lat=0 degrees, dip lat =10, 15 etc

Answer (score 1):

interesting question!

I'm the dev of [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps), a library intended to simplify creating exactly this kind of custom geo-data analysis widgets, so I got interested :-)

I had a quick look at your data... its a quite strange netcdf and I have no clue what defines the line you use to identify the points so I just re-used your code to extract the data.

Here's a quick solution that uses a KDTree to identify the closest points with respect to the line-points... Its not 100% exact since it identifies those points with respect to a max. distance defined in degrees and not actual distance on the globe, but it works well enough and I think you should be able to take it from here if you need something more exact...

Its also important to notice that this method will show you the actual data and not some interpolated points created by the algorithm used to display the data! (so the line will not be nice and smooth but it will only show the actual data values closest to the line)

[image]

```py
from pathlib import Path
from itertools import chain

from scipy.spatial import KDTree
import xarray as xar
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from eomaps import Maps


# --------------------------------------------- read the data
p = Path(r"GOLD_data-20230319T161539Z-001\GOLD_data")

with xar.open_dataset(p / "GOLD_L1C_CHA_NI1_2018_286_23_10_v04_r01_c01.nc") as ncfile:
    lon, lat = ncfile.REFERENCE_POINT_LON.values, ncfile.REFERENCE_POINT_LAT.values
    wavelength = ncfile.WAVELENGTH.values
    radiance = ncfile.RADIANCE.values

O5s_ids = np.argwhere((134.3 <= wavelength[50,25,:]) & (wavelength[50,25,:] <= 137.7))
O5s = np.array(np.nansum(radiance[:,:,O5s_ids],axis = 2))*.04 # integrate under the peak!
O5s = np.transpose(O5s[:,:,0])
x=lon[9:-8,9:-8]
y=lat[9:-8,9:-8]
z=O5s[9:-8,9:-8].T


Mag = pd.read_csv(p / "mag_cords.csv")
X_dip10s,Y_dip10s = Mag.LON10S.to_numpy(),Mag.LAT10S.to_numpy()
line = np.column_stack((X_dip10s, Y_dip10s))


# --------------------------------------------- create a new map
m = Maps(ax=211, crs=4326)
m.set_extent((-61.8,-20.5,-1.5,24.5))
m.add_feature.preset.coastline()
m.add_feature.preset.ocean()

# plot the data
m.set_data(data=z, x=x, y=y, crs=4326)
m.set_shape.ellipses(radius=0.35)
m.set_classify.UserDefined(bins=np.linspace(0, 20, 11))
m.plot_map(cmap="viridis", vmin=0, vmax=28)
m.add_colorbar(orientation="vertical")

# add a normal matplotlib axis (and share x-limits)
ax = m.f.add_subplot(212)
ax.sharex(m.ax)
# turn off navigation on the normal matplotlib plot
ax.set_navigate(False)

# position axes 
m.apply_layout(
    {'figsize': [6.95, 4.8],
     '0_map': [0.1, 0.44678, 0.5875, 0.53552],
     '1_cb': [0.75, 0.04546, 0.2125, 0.95484],
     '1_cb_histogram_size': 0.8,
     '2_': [0.1, 0.10859, 0.5875, 0.32578]}
    )

# setup a new map-layer (will be used to draw identified points)
m2 = m.new_layer()

# --------------------------------------------- identify points along line
tree = KDTree(np.column_stack((x.ravel(), y.ravel())))

def get_lineoffset(pos, **kwargs):
    # get the offset required to shift the line to the click position
    x, y = line.T
    minxid = np.argmin(abs(pos[0] - x))
    offset = pos[1] - y[minxid]
    return offset

def identify_points(pts, max_dist):
    # identify closest points with respect to the line
    tree2 = KDTree(pts)
    q = tree2.query_ball_tree(tree, max_dist)
    q = list(chain(*[i for i in q if len(i) > 0]))
    coords = tree.data[q].T
    data = z.ravel()[q]
    return coords, data

def indicate_found_points(pts, offset=0, max_dist=1):
    # offset line
    pts = pts + [0, offset]
    # identify closest points
    coords, data = identify_points(pts, max_dist=max_dist)
    
    # plot identified points on the map (replace on each click)
    m2.set_data(data, coords[0], coords[1])
    m2.set_shape.ellipses(radius=0.2)
    m2.plot_map(set_extent=False, zorder=2, fc="r")
    
    # sort found points so we can plot a line
    sortp = np.argsort(coords[0])
    lx, ly = coords[0][sortp], data[sortp]    
    
    # plot a line on the map
    l, = m.ax.plot(*pts.T, c="r", lw=0.5)
    # remove it on next pick
    m.cb.pick.add_temporary_artist(l)
    
    # plot data on normal matpltoib plot
    l2, = ax.plot(lx, ly, lw=0.25, c="k", zorder=0)
    # color points same as in the map
    sc = ax.scatter(lx, ly, c=ly, s=10, norm=m._norm, cmap=m._cbcmap)
    # remove it on next pick
    m.cb.pick.add_temporary_artist(l2)
    m.cb.pick.add_temporary_artist(sc)

    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    m.redraw()

def callback(pos, max_dist=1, **kwargs):
    offset = get_lineoffset(pos)
    indicate_found_points(line, offset=offset, max_dist=max_dist)

# attach the callback to the map
m.cb.pick.attach(callback, max_dist=0.75)
```

Comment: This looks like an excellent solution. I installed using the minicondas Dbn but when I run this command "from eomaps import Maps"                                                                                                               Error:           " ImportError: cannot import name 'TriMesh' from 'matplotlib.tri' (C:\Users\simba\miniconda3\envs\eomaps\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tri\__init__.py)"

Comment: Hey, this is because you are using `matplotlib v3.5.x`... an update to `matplotlib v3.6.x` should solve the problem!  (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/24105)   (I'll have to implement a backport for this so that older versions work as well...)

Comment: Hie https://stackoverflow.com/users/9703451/raphael, I actually have matplotlib              3.7.1 installed on my miniconda. Should I downgrade to 3.6.0?

Comment: Hey, that is indeed unexpected... Is it possible that you use an old EOmaps version? (since `eomaps v4.4.3` `TriMesh` is no longer imported from `matplotlib.tri`...) I just tested with `eomaps v6.3` and `matplotlib v3.7.1` and I don't get any issue...   I've opened an issue concerning v3.5.x [here](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps/issues/159)... if you provide some details on your setup I can try to help pinpoint your issue.

Comment: Hey where can I get these details?

Comment: I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps) I ran this command again  "mamba install -c conda-forge eomaps" so it installed but upon importing Eosmaps it says package not installed. I tried using pip and conda to install it says "No matching dbn found for EOsmaps.                                        "I checked my working Envt ,"# conda environments:
#
                         C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
base                  *  C:\Users\simba\miniconda3
eomaps                   C:\Users\simba\miniconda3\envs\eomaps"

Comment: Hey @LordHammer, without additional info on your environment its very hard to pinpoint where things go wrong... if you open a dedicated issue [here](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps/issues) and include the output of `conda list` i can try to help...   alternatively simply creating a new env using `mamba create -n eomaps_env -c conda-forge eomaps numpy pandas scipy netcdf4 xarray ` should also do the job